# Can't run yum update

Tags: yum, centos

I've been banging my head on the keyboard with this! I'm working on CentOS 6.5 x86_64.

Firstly I tried to update `php` and `apache` using easy apache. The update failed very quickly so I went on the usual hunt around the internet. It appears I also can't run `yum update`. Here is the bottom of the readout:

```
Error: Package: glibc-utils-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libgd.so.2()(64bit)
       Removing: gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           libgd.so.2()(64bit)
       Updated By: gd-2.1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (CentALT)
           Not found
Error: Package: cpanel-webalizer-2.23_05-2.cp1136.x86_64 (installed)
       Requires: libgd.so.2()(64bit)
       Removing: gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           libgd.so.2()(64bit)
       Updated By: gd-2.1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (CentALT)
           Not found
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've tried running `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` but to no avail.

A lot of what I have read mentions repos. I have the following repos installed:

```
CentOS-Base.repo
CentOS-Vault.repo
mod-pagespeed.repo
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
epel.repo
remi.repo
centalt.repo
CentOS-Media.repo
epel-testing.repo
```

I know there is a problem with `centalt.repo` as when I try to go to the base URL I get a `403:forbidden` message.

I've tried using `wget` to install `gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm` but it says it's already installed. Which, to me, means `libgd.so.2()(64bit)` should also be installed (according to http://www.rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/centos/6.5/x86_64/Packages/gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.html).

I'm really stuck here... I really hope someone can help me get this sorted out. I need to update PHP for a client.

Comment: so you're running cpanel?

Comment: First troubleshooting step should be to investigate how the CentALT repo is broken. Maybe they changed the path and this box didn't get the update? I would check their website and then manually dig into the repo settings. It obviously worked at one time...

Comment: Try running `yum clean all && yum upgrade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply repoint the `.repo` file for CentALT to one of the mirrors. The main repository indeed seems to be down, I'm only able to browse their top level URL, all the YUM URLs are returning a 403 Forbidden.

Here's one such mirror:

- http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/CentALT/6/

You can change the `/etc/yum.repo.d/centos.alt.ru.repo` file like so:

```
[CentALT]
name=CentALT Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
baseurl=http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/CentALT/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

#### References

- [CentALT readme.txt](http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/CentALT/readme.txt)